# Linq To Entities Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Consider the following Query :

```
var profilelst =
    (
        from i in dbContext.ProspectProfiles
        where i.CreateId == currentUser
        select new ProspectProfile
        {
            ProspectId = i.ProspectId,
            Live = i.Live,
            Name = i.Name,
            ServiceETA = i.Opportunities.OrderByDescending(t => t.FollowUpDate)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .ServiceETA.ToString(),
            FollowUpDate = i.Opportunities.OrderByDescending(t => t.FollowUpDate)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .FollowUpDate
        }
    )
    .ToList();

return profilelst.OrderByDescending(c=>c.FollowUpDate)
        .Skip(0).Take(endIndex)
        .ToList();
```

Here in this query please take a look at `FollowUpDate` and `ServiceType`, these both i have fetched from Opportunity table, is there any other work around to get these both..

One to Many Relationship in tables is like: `ProspectProfile -> Opportunities`

Whether the query i have written is ok or is there any another work around that can be done in easier way.

Comment: Reformatted code to make it readable, however, the actual question isn't clear.

Comment: Did you test if your first query works at all? I have doubts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you can improve is to avoid ordering twice by changing your code to this:

```
var profilelst
  = dbContext.ProspectProfiles
             .Where(i => i.CreateId == currentUser)
             .Select(i => 
                    {
                        var opportunity
                           = i.Opportunities
                              .OrderByDescending(t => t.FollowUpDate)
                              .First();
                        return new ProspectProfile
                        {
                            ProspectId = i.ProspectId,
                            Live = i.Live, 
                            Name = i.Name,
                            ServiceETA = opportunity.ServiceETA.ToString(),
                            FollowUpDate = opportunity.FollowUpDate
                        }
                    }).ToList();

return profilelst.OrderByDescending(c => c.FollowUpDate).Take(endIndex).ToList();
```

I made several changes to your original query:

1. I changed it to use method chains syntax. It is just so much easier to read in my opinion.
2. I removed the unnecessary `Skip(0)`.
3. The biggest change is in the `Select` part:

   1. I changed `FirstOrDefault` to `First`, because you are accessing the properties of the return value anyway. This will throw a descriptive exception if no opportunity exists. That's better than what you had: In your case it would throw a `NullReferenceException`. That's bad, `NullReferenceExceptions` always indicate a bug in your program and are not descriptive at all.
   2. I moved the part that selects the opportunity out of the initializer, so we need to do the sorting only once instead of twice.

Comment: I don't think that this will work with LINQ to Entities because projecting into an entity is not supported, `First()` is not supported in a projection and I have doubt that using a local variable in the `Select` expression is supported.

Comment: @Slauma: Good point. Care to provide an alternative solution?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: I've tried now an answer. I didn't answer at once because I was confused about the query in the question which has partially the same flaws as your query. In the meantime I believe that the query in the question is untested and it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few problems in your query:

- You cannot project into an entity (`select new ProspectProfile`). LINQ to Entities only supports projections into anonymous types (`select new`) or other types which are not part of your entity data model (`select new MySpecialType`)
- `ToString()` for a numeric or `DateTime` type is not supported in LINQ to Entities (`ServiceETA.ToString()`)
- `FirstOrDefault().ServiceETA` (or `FollowUpdate`) will throw an exception if the `Opportunities` collection is empty and `ServiceETA` is a non-nullable value type (such as `DateTime`) because EF cannot materialize any value into such a variable.
- Using `.ToList()` after your first query will execute the query in the database and load the full result. Your later `Take` happens in memory on the full list, not in the database. (You effectively load the whole result list from the database into memory and then throw away all objects except the first you have `Take`en.

To resolve all four problems you can try the following:

```
var profilelst = dbContext.ProspectProfiles
    .Where(p => p.CreateId == currentUser)
    .Select(p => new
    {
        ProspectId = p.ProspectId,
        Live = p.Live,
        Name = p.Name,
        LastOpportunity = p.Opportunities
           .OrderByDescending(o => o.FollowUpDate)
           .Select(o => new
           {
               ServiceETA = o.ServiceETA,
               FollowUpDate = o.FollowUpDate
           })
           .FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastOpportunity.FollowUpDate)
    .Skip(startIndex)  // can be removed if startIndex is 0
    .Take(endIndex)
    .ToList();
```

This will give you a list of anonymous objects. If you need the result in a list of your entity `ProspectProfile` you must copy the values after this query. Note that `LastOpportunity` can be `null` in the result if a `ProspectProfile` has no `Opportunities`.